# Summing over all but one axis

Tags: python, numpy, sum

Several times, I've dealt with an ND array, such as

```
foo = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3, 3))
```

and then I would have a dimension over which I want to preserve the variable from the next operation. Say the next operation is `mean`, in which case

```
preserveAxis = 1
desiredOutcome = foo.mean(axis=0).mean(axis=1)
```

the previous is my desired outcome, since I first take the average over the 0th axis, and then over the 2nd axis (which has become the 1st after the initial operation). That is, **I've done the operation over axis 0 and 2, but preserved axis 1**.

This type of procedure is cumbersome, and most importantly not generic. I'm looking for a generic way to preserve one axis, but sum/mean over all others. How could I achieve this best, preferably within `numpy`?

Comment: can you elaborate *to preserve the variable from the next operation*?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Is that clearer now? I'm not certain I'm using generally accepted language here, so feel free to recommend changes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one generalized to n-dim cases for reduction [`ufuncs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/ufuncs.html) -

```
def reduce_skipfew(ufunc, foo, preserveAxis=None):
    r = np.arange(foo.ndim)   
    if preserveAxis is not None:
        preserveAxis = tuple(np.delete(r, preserveAxis))
    return ufunc(foo, axis=preserveAxis)
```

Sample run -

```
In [171]: reduce_skipfew(np.mean, foo, preserveAxis=1)
Out[171]: array([10., 13., 16.])

In [172]: foo = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3, 3))

In [173]: reduce_skipfew(np.mean, foo, preserveAxis=1)
Out[173]: array([10., 13., 16.])

In [174]: reduce_skipfew(np.sum, foo, preserveAxis=1)
Out[174]: array([ 90, 117, 144])

# preserve none i.e. sum all
In [175]: reduce_skipfew(np.sum, foo, preserveAxis=None)
Out[175]: 351

# preserve more than one axis
In [176]: reduce_skipfew(np.sum, foo, preserveAxis=(0,2)) 
Out[176]: 
array([[ 9, 12, 15],
       [36, 39, 42],
       [63, 66, 69]])
```

Comment: Good generalized solution!

Answer (score 4):

You can use tuples for the axis parameter:

```
foo.mean(axis=(0, 2))
```

If your array have a variable number of dimensions and/or the preserved dimension is can vary, it can be al little more tricky. See @Divakar's answer.